# Override default xml in Magento 2.1 for header customization

Tags: php, xml, magento2

I am trying to override default.xml from **vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout** to **app/design/frontend/my_module/my_project/layout/** .

But its not overriding. Below is my code:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="3columns" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="default_head_blocks"/>
    <body>
        <block name="require.js" class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::page/js/require_js.phtml" />
        <referenceContainer name="after.body.start">
            <block class="Magento\RequireJs\Block\Html\Head\Config" name="requirejs-config"/>
            <block class="Magento\Translation\Block\Html\Head\Config" name="translate-config"/>
            <block class="Magento\Translation\Block\Js" name="translate" template="Magento_Translation::translate.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Js\Cookie" name="js_cookies" template="Magento_Theme::js/cookie.phtml"/>
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Notices" name="global_notices" template="html/notices.phtml"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceBlock name="top.links">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header" name="header" as="header" before="-">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="show_part" xsi:type="string">welcome</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
        <referenceContainer name="main.content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="skip_to_content.target" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/skiptarget.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="target_id" xsi:type="string">contentarea</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="header.container">
            <container name="header.panel.wrapper" htmlClass="panel wrapper" htmlTag="div" before="-">
                <container name="header.panel" label="Page Header Panel" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="panel header">
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="skip_to_content" template="Magento_Theme::html/skip.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="target" xsi:type="string">contentarea</argument>
                            <argument name="label" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Skip to Content</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_language" as="store_language" template="switch/languages.phtml"/>
                    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="top.links">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">header links</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </container>
            </container>
            <container name="header-wrapper" label="Page Header" as="header-wrapper" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="header content">
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" name="logo">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="logo_img_width" xsi:type="number">189</argument>
                        <argument name="logo_img_height" xsi:type="number">64</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="page.top">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="navigation.sections" before="-" template="Magento_Theme::html/sections.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="group_name" xsi:type="string">navigation-sections</argument>
                    <argument name="group_css" xsi:type="string">nav-sections</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.menu" group="navigation-sections" template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Menu</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu" name="catalog.topnav" template="html/topmenu.phtml" ttl="3600" before="-"/>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Text" name="store.links" group="navigation-sections">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Account</argument>
                        <argument name="use_force" xsi:type="boolean">true</argument>
                        <argument name="text" xsi:type="string"><![CDATA[<!-- Account links -->]]></argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.settings" group="navigation-sections" template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Settings</argument>
                    </arguments>
                    <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store.settings.language" template="switch/languages.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="id_modifier" xsi:type="string">nav</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                    <block class="Magento\Directory\Block\Currency" name="store.settings.currency" template="currency.phtml">
                        <arguments>
                            <argument name="id_modifier" xsi:type="string">nav</argument>
                        </arguments>
                    </block>
                </block>
            </block>
            <container name="top.container" as="topContainer" label="After Page Header Top" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="top-container"/>
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Breadcrumbs" name="breadcrumbs" as="breadcrumbs"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="columns.top">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Title" name="page.main.title" template="html/title.phtml"/>
            <container name="page.messages" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="page messages">
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="ajax.message.placeholder" template="Magento_Theme::html/messages.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Messages" name="messages" as="messages" template="Magento_Theme::messages.phtml"/>
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="main">
            <container name="content.top" label="Main Content Top"/>
            <container name="content" label="Main Content Area"/>
            <container name="content.aside" label="Main Content Aside"/>
            <container name="content.bottom" label="Main Content Bottom"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="page.bottom.container">
            <container name="page.bottom" label="Before Page Footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="content"/>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="footer-container">
            <container name="footer" as="footer" label="Page Footer" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="footer content">
                <block class="Magento\Store\Block\Switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher" template="switch/stores.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Links" name="footer_links">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">footer links</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="copyright" template="html/copyright.phtml"/>
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="report.bugs" template="Magento_Theme::html/bugreport.phtml" />
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="before.body.end">
            <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Footer" name="absolute_footer" template="html/absolute_footer.phtml" />
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\FormKey" name="formkey"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

Please suggest me a way to do this. I am trying this to customize the header in Magento 2.1. Kindly give me an idea to customize header. Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

Your XML path in the module is incorrect. It should be like this:

```
vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout/default.xml to app/code/my_module/my_project/view/frontend/layout/default.xml .
```

Answer (score 0):

Just you need to set your theme type to 0 instead of 1 in theme table,

**Please use this query to fix the issue:**

/* this will be used to check the type */

```
select type from theme where theme_path='your_theme_name';
```

> If type = 1 then we need to set it as 0

to set it to 0 use the below query,

```
update theme set type = 0 where theme_path='your_theme_name';
```

after doing this you need to refresh the cache.

Here 0 represents Magento default theme layout

That's it, Now you can be able to use override default.xml